# How to know inferencing/reasoning level of any RDF

Tags: rdf, jena, reasoning

I am new in this area; I would like to know how to know the level of inferencing/reasoning supported by RDF, any idea to calculate the level of inferencing in Jena.

Looking forward to your kind reply

Comment: What is the level of inferencing?

Comment: In Jena, it is a choice. Documentation: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/